# error in ffmpeg when sending image from pipe via php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, pipe

used the following tutorial to send an uploaded image to ffmpeg from php via pipe.

[Image pipe from php to ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302710/image-pipe-from-php-to-ffmpeg)

however it raises an eror saying that the pipe has invalid data in it.

```
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

following is the php code for uploading an image file

```
$tempPath = $_FILES['vdofile']['tmp_name'];

print_r($tempPath);

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
    );

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempPath);

 $proc = proc_open("ffmpeg image2pipe -i - -y image.jpg", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

 if (is_resource($proc)) {     
     /*
      * $pipes[0] = write something to command being run
      * $pipes[1] = read something from command
      * $pipes[2] = error from command 
      */
       fwrite($pipes[0], $_FILES['vdofile']['tmp_name']);
       fclose($pipes[0]);
 }
 proc_close($proc);
?>
```

and simple html uploading code is as follows:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="vdofile" />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

the error file generated is as follows:

```
    ffmpeg version N-58485-ga12b4bd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 26 2013 22:07:02 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 55.100 / 52. 55.100
  libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavformat    55. 21.102 / 55. 21.102
  libavdevice    55.  5.101 / 55.  5.101
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

any assistance will be appreciated.

**

### EDIT

**

the code still produces an error:

```
    ffmpeg version N-58485-ga12b4bd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 26 2013 22:07:02 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 55.100 / 52. 55.100
  libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavformat    55. 21.102 / 55. 21.102
  libavdevice    55.  5.101 / 55.  5.101
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[image2pipe @ 00000000029ee0a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
pipe:: could not find codec parameters
```

the following ffmpeg comand is called from within php like above:

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f mjpeg image.mp4
```

Comment: You need to show your actual, unscripted ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output. Does the output file play fine despite the error?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: thank you for comment, the ffmpeg code is executed from within php . may not be able to directly run the command (how to pass the uploaded file as piped input . 
the output file is not generated at all. (output expected for test purposes in a single image) i.e. was testing to save the uploaded image to jpg just to test php-ffmpeg pipe communication

Comment: The ffmpeg console output is always important information when trying to get help using ffmpeg.

Comment: What format are the images being piped to ffmpeg?

Comment: the image format is jpg/jpeg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42893/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-abdul-ali)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, and you need to tell ffmpeg what format the pipe image is:

Change:

```
ffmpeg image2pipe -i - -y image.jpg
```

To:

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -codec:v mjpeg -i - image.jpg
```

This example will re-encode your input piped image to `image.jpg`.

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -codec:v mjpeg -i - -codec copy image.jpg
```

This will simply [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) instead of re-encoding. Think of it as a copy and paste of the piped image to the output.

---

You may still get `pipe:: Input/output error` but you can probably ignore it as the stream copied image has the same md5 hash as the input in my test.

I see no reason to pipe a single image to ffmpeg to re-encode it, but I see that your code is simply for testing the pipe.